# Pass data to redirect page when redirecting on netlify

Tags: javascript, netlify

I have a netlify site built with just html, css, js.
I understand I can add a _redirect file to my project root that handles the routes that redirects all routes to a given page like so.

```
/* /index.html 200
```

If the user navigates to /brad it should redirect to /index.html.

My aim is to avoid creating a .Html file for every route.
However I want to be able to keep the path as a variable (brad) or pass the path to the page. I want to access the variable (brad) in the js in index.html .
My intention is to make a different action based on the path name. So /brad will work differently from /susan (where susan might be a user on the site).

An example would be if the user is not logged in log them in and send them to */brad* (brad's profile page) after they log in or 404 page if no user brad exists. Here I need to keep track of which path the user originally accessed to know where to send them afterwards.

I know in server side code like php, laravel you can pass a redirect->with($variable) based on which route was accessed which can be accessed on the page that the user is redirected to.

**Is it possible to pass the path of redirects on netlify as a variable to the js in the /index.html?**

If no, would netlify be a bad option for sites that need to display dynamic routes such as [www.example.com/profile/1](http://www.example.com/profile/1) ? Should I go for a traditional server solution with a separate backend?

I use firebase for authentication and storing user data.

Comment: A trick you can use is to make the 404 page redirect the routs instead of the _redirect file, so you can redirect users from /brad to /?from=brad.

Comment: If I get you right I am going to get the url parameters from window.location.href on my site 404 page and redirect to my routes page with the path as a parameter. I will give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment from @ChalanaN, I created a 404.html page at the root of my project. *Netlify displays this page for all non-existent routes.*  The page contains a script that gets the last parameter in the url and adds it as a query parameter on the link to the redirected page.

In 404.html

```
<script>
let givenPath = window.location.href.split('/').pop();//get the element after the last '/' in the url
window.location.href= '/index.html'+'?q='+givenPath;
</script>
```

In index.html

```
<script>
let redirectPath =window.location.href.split('=').pop();
</script>
```

Here the variable `redirectPath` will contain the original path the user accessed.

So [www.example.com/brad.html](http://www.example.com/brad.html) will redirect to **'...index.html?q=brad.html'** with 'brad.html' as the final content in the `redirectPath` variable and now you have the redirect path in a js variable.

A warning: using 'index.html/?q=' will give a cannot get index.html/ 404 on your local machine when using live server so make sure there is no / before the page to be redirected if you intend to test locally.

*As a sidenote, you could use window.location.pathname to get the path but that returns the path with the '/' attached to the path the user entered.*